# How to find out where blx branches to

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

so I have this instruction: blx r3.

Through debugging, I found that the r3 address is 0xe2fcd839 and r3 contains e9 f0 4f 89 b0 0d 46 ce 49 00 2d 79 44 09 68 09.

How do can I figure out where the instruction is branching to?

Comment: r3 is 32 bits how did  you fit 128 bits in there?

Answer (score 0):

`blx r3` sets PC = R3

Except it's an odd address so that means transfer to Thumb state and actually set `PC = R3 & ~1`.  (i.e. clear the low bit and use that as the address)

So the bytes in memory pointed to by R3 are fetched as code.